# How to know the Field of View Angle of iPhone or iPad's Camera

Tags: ios, camera

In Android, the API provides the field of view angle:

1. `Camera.Parameters.getHorizontalViewAngle()`
2. `Camera.Parameters.getVerticalViewAngle()`

**What's the equivalent in iOS?**
I don't want to pre-write those values because it's not flexible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what "horizontal" and "vertical" mean in this context, but I think of two calculations, the rotation about the "z" axis (i.e. how level we are with the horizon in the photo), and how much it's tilted forward and backward (i.e. the rotation about the "x" axis, namely is it pointing up or down). You can do this using [Core Motion](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CoreMotion_Reference/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009686). Just [add it to your project](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html) and then you can do something like:

1. Make sure to import CoreMotion header:

   ```
   #import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>
   ```
2. Define a few class properties:

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, strong) CMMotionManager *motionManager;
   @property (nonatomic, strong) NSOperationQueue *deviceQueue;
   ```
3. Start the motion manager:

   ```
   - (void)startMotionManager
   {
       self.deviceQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
       self.motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
       self.motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 5.0 / 60.0;

       [self.motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame:CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitraryZVertical
                                                               toQueue:self.deviceQueue
                                                           withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error)
       {
           [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
               CGFloat x = motion.gravity.x;
               CGFloat y = motion.gravity.y;
               CGFloat z = motion.gravity.z;

               // how much is it rotated around the z axis

               CGFloat rotationAngle = atan2(y, x) + M_PI_2;                  // in radians
               CGFloat rotationAngleDegrees = rotationAngle * 180.0f / M_PI;  // in degrees

               // how far it it tilted forward and backward

               CGFloat r = sqrtf(x*x + y*y + z*z);
               CGFloat tiltAngle = (r == 0.0 ? 0.0 : acosf(z/r);              // in radians
               CGFloat tiltAngleDegrees = tiltAngle * 180.0f / M_PI - 90.0f); // in degrees
           }];
       }];
   }
   ```
4. When done, stop the motion manager:

   ```
   - (void)stopMotionManager
   {
       [self.motionManager stopDeviceMotionUpdates];
       self.motionManager = nil;
       self.deviceQueue = nil;
   }
   ```

I'm not doing anything with the values here, but you can save them in class properties which you can then access elsewhere in your app. Or you could dispatch UI updates back to the main queue right from here. A bunch of options.

Since this is iOS 5 and higher, if the app is supporting earlier versions you might also want to weakly link Core Motion then then check to see everything is ok, and if not, just realize that you're not going to be capturing the orientation of the device:

```
if ([CMMotionManager class]) 
{
    // ok, core motion exists
}
```

And, in case you're wondering about my fairly arbitrary choice of twelve times per second, in the [Event Handling Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/motion_event_basics/motion_event_basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH6-SW15), they suggest 10-20/second if just checking the orientation of the device.

Comment: I mean Field of View Angle of the camera.

Comment: @BingchenYang lol. Sorry I misunderstood the question. The API for inquiring/controlling the camera is a little basic in iOS. Hopefully some else can help you here, but there's a good chance you might not be able to do this (short of maintaining table of effective focal lengths and looking up devices and whether using front or rear camera).

Comment: Thanks for the effort. That seems a lot of work. I've found some related material on site http://www.caramba-apps.com/blog/files/field-of-view-angles-ipad-iphone.html   But still it would be better if there is a way to know the camera speifications via API

Comment: @BingchenYang Agreed. Your link is like the ones I found (though I was searching for "effective focal length", the bottom line is equivalent). Sadly, Apple has been reluctant to make their private camera API to the camera and make it a public interface (despite suggestions at one point that they were going to open their kimono). Maybe there's some public interface that's eluding me thus far, but I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 7.0+, you can obtain FOV angle of a camera by reading this property.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedeviceformat/1624569-videofieldofview?language=objc

```
AVCaptureDevice *camera;
camera = ...
float fov = [[camera activeFormat] videoFieldOfView];
NSLog("FOV=%f(deg)", fov);
```