# How to measure user distance from wall

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera, distance

I need to measure distance of wall from user. When user open the camera and point to the any surface i need to get the distance. I have read some link Is it possible to measure distance to object with camera? and i used code for find the iphone camera angle from here http://blog.sallarp.com/iphone-accelerometer-device-orientation.

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration
{
    // Get the current device angle
    float xx = -[acceleration x];
    float yy = [acceleration y];
    float angle = atan2(yy, xx);
}

d = h * tan angle

But nothing happen in the nslog and camera.
```

Comment: Why should anything happen in NSLog or camera? I don't see any code that does that. Also you need some infrared light to measure a distance or a CV library to compute something like this. Just the accelerometer won't help you.

Comment: This code is used to determine the physical orientation of the device in space, but it tells you nothing about the distance to other objects.

Comment: The main CV library I've seen for iOS is openCV.

Comment: I need to do like this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PBpRZWmPyKo. What should i do?

Comment: Can anyone please give me the idea to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments, you shared a link to a video: http://youtube.com/watch?v=PBpRZWmPyKo.

That app is not doing anything particularly sophisticated with the camera, but rather appears to be calculate distances using basic trigonometry, and it accomplishes this by constraining the business problem in several critical ways:

1. First, the app requires the user to specify the height at which the phone's camera lens is being held.
2. Second, the user is measuring the distance to something sitting on the ground and aligning the bottom of that to some known location on the screen (meaning you have a right triangle).

Those two constraints, combined with the accelerometer and the camera's lens focal length, would allow you to calculate the distance.

If your target cross-hair was in the center of the screen, it greatly simplifies the problem and it becomes a matter of simple trigonometry, i.e. your `d = h * tan(angle)`.

BTW, the "angle" code in the question appears to measure the rotation about the z-axis, the clockwise/counter-clockwise rotation as the device faces you. For this problem, though, you want to measure the rotation of the device about its x-axis, the forward/backward tilt. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16555778/1271826 for example of how to capture the device orientation in space. Also, that answer uses CoreMotion, whereas the article referenced in your question is using an API that has since been deprecated.

Comment: Other tricks include pointing camera at something of known size. Or using CoreLocation for rough distances to items of known location. But there's no general capability to "point camera at wall and calculate distance."

Comment: How can i achieve this?                                               A possible solution is using distance to pixel ratio and use results from a training set to calibrate the Z-axis. 
                                                                     For e.g. Use a small block on one corner of your projection and as you move close or away to the wall, that block size will increase/decrease respectively. Then calculate the scaling factor using the actual distance and the block pixel count.

Comment: Are you talking about doing this to calculate the distance? I don't see how that would work, unless you know either the height of the item that you're pointing it as well as the height of the camera, or the size of the item that you're pointing at.

Answer (score -1):

The only way this would be possible is if you could read out the setting of the auto-focus mechanism in the lens. To my knowledge this is not possible.